# Android Google Map update geofence area/radius on drag

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, android-geofence, android-maps-utils

Hoping that you are aware with android map's Geofencing feature where we can draw/highlight particular area (radius of circle in meter) on Google map as displayed below.

My requirement is that I need to change this area by dragging circle border. Please share your ideas to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: http://www.freemaptools.com/radius-around-point.htm

Check this link.
Might be this is done using JS code.

You need to play bit with google.maps.MVCObject.

Comment: @umesh I need similar in android. Any of  'Native' (Java) & 'Cross' (Html, Css, JS) development is fine.

Comment: Do You find any Salutation for this, Kindly let me know

Comment: @pankajsharma check this https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions. It has workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using google maps drawing tools api. Please refer link for the same: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools